# R barplot straight horizontal line

Tags: r

My code is below

```
data <-read.csv("Results_15Jan2015.csv") 
PartNo <- data$PartNo
TotalTime <- data$TOTAL_TIME

mp <- barplot(height = TotalTime, main = "Plot of Total Time for different Part Numbers", xlab =   "Different Part Numbers", ylab = "Total Time (sec)", xlim = c(1,42), ylim = c(0,max(TotalTime)+30), 
    col = rainbow(nrow(data)))
text(mp, par("usr")[3], labels = PartNo, srt = 45, adj = c(1.1,1.1), xpd = TRUE, cex=.9)
abline(h=mean(TotalTime))

specify_decimal <- function(x, k) format(round(x, k), nsmall=k)
text(7.5,mean(TotalTime)+25, paste("Average =",specify_decimal(mean(TotalTime),3)))
```

2 Questions:
a) Why is my horizontal line not drawn all the way to the right of the plot? How to draw the horizontal line all the way to the right?

b) I have a total of 42 observations, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/plchd.jpg
   but the total number of bars shown is only 37, why? See https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaaeA.jpg

I need to display all 42 bars in a single plot. how do I do that? thanks

Comment: That you are missing 5 observations could be due to ``NA`` entries; have you checked your data? What happens if you leave out the ``xlim`` argument?

Answer (score 3):

As MrGrumble said, dropping the xlim argument should solve both of your problems (the line and missing bars). It might not be straightforward what this argument does in barplot function, as you don't give x explicitly. See in this example:

```
x <-seq(15)

barplot(x,xlim=c(1,15))

abline(h=6)
```

Gives a graphic with issues similar to those you are having, whereas

```
x <-seq(15)

barplot(x)

abline(h=6)
```

Behaves "as expected"

Comment: BARVO, THANK YOU (Cristian and MrGrumble) VERY MUCH. It works for me.